# Error in kaobook style - undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, document-classes, undefined, kaobook

I get the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \DeclareTOCStyleEntries 
                                   [indent=0em,numwidth=2em,dynnumwidth=yes]...
l.843 }
```

when trying to run anything using the [class kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook), including the examples that come with it. This particular error is in the Report example.

It says the error is in the kao.sty document. I've looked through this and can't find the issue. Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: Is that the first error message you get? Often with LaTeX only the first error message is relevant, later error messages can be knock-on effects. Your LaTeX complains about `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` being undefined. There are several possible reasons for this and it is hard to say without more details (a `.log` file of the LaTeX run, a short example document reproducing the error, ...), but my first guess would be to check first if all packages that are requested are found (if not there should be an error) and if your packages are up-to-date (maybe `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries` is fairly new).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the `kaobook` class from the link you provided and all accompanying files.

The `main.tex` file included in the `minimal_report` directory will compile fine (except for the missing file `report-template.bib`, LaTeX will issue warnings. so I added one) as long as it is in the same directory as all the others `.sty` and `.cls` files included in the distribution.

[image: b]

This is the (invented) `report-template.bib`

```
@book{James2013,
    title={Analytical chemistry of foods},
    author={James, Ceirwyn S},
    date=2013,
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
```